# Three part dated item for CV

Tags: tables, minipage, cv

I want the section of my CV for presentations to be formatted something like this

[image]

This it the code I have been using:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{minipage}[t]{6cm} 
Title of the presentation which may be multiple lines 
\end{minipage}
\hfill{\begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}
Conference name which can also be quite long
\end{minipage} -- Month Year}
\end{itemize}
```

I would like to see if it is possible to do this in some sort of tabular environment. It would also be nice if instead of just having the sizes be 6cm, it was based on the size of the text so that something like a long title with a short conference name could fit on one line.